# Extract specific data from an array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, object

I'am trying to achieve something but i'am stucked. I want to get the [url] value from a multidimensional array and assign it to 'media_url'.

Even when I try to reach the very first value with $media['media_url']->_compiledPropertyMapLink->taken_at['arrayDepth'], I get an error.

In my controller:

```
foreach ($media->getItems() as $media) {

    if(is_null($media)) continue;

    $top_engagement_rate_array[$media->getCode()] = array(
        'media_url' => $media['media_url']->_compiledPropertyMapLink->taken_at['arrayDepth'],
        //'media' => array($media),
    );

}
```

This is my dump:

```
Array
(
    [Bz8GtKsnLnd] => Array
        (
            [likes] => 521
            [comments] => 8
            [engagement] => 47.83
            [type] => 1
            [media_url] => InstagramAPI\Response\Model\Item Object
                (
                    [_compiledPropertyMapLink:LazyJsonMapper\LazyJsonMapper:private] => Array
                        (

                            [pk] => LazyJsonMapper\Property\PropertyDefinition Object
                                (
                                    [arrayDepth] => 0
                                    [propType] => string
                                    [isObjectType] => 
                                )

                            [id] => LazyJsonMapper\Property\PropertyDefinition Object
                                (
                                    [arrayDepth] => 0
                                    [propType] => string
                                    [isObjectType] => 
                                )

                        )

                    [_objectData:LazyJsonMapper\LazyJsonMapper:private] => Array
                        (
                            [taken_at] => 2938347
                            [pk] => 2088573819334474205
                            [id] => 2088573819334474205_30166788676
                            [device_timestamp] => 65498580560192
                            [media_type] => 1
                            [code] => Bz8GtKsnLnd
                            [client_cache_key] => MjA4ODU3MzgxOTMzNDQ3NDIwNQ==.2
                            [filter_type] => 0
                            [image_versions2] => Array
                                (
                                    [candidates] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [width] => 1080
                                                    [height] => 1296
                                                    [url] => https://scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/67445783_1525436337029385856597176_2032750876827734854_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=108&se=7&oh=388f051c1ebe3b148a5fe740db089011&oe=5E38E802&ig_cache_key=MjA4ODU3MzgxOTMzNDQ3NDIwNQ%3D%3D.2


                                                )
```

Thank you people for helping me with this.